# Можно ли указать в конструкторе конкретный адрес размешения объекта?

Tags: c++, микроконтроллеры, stm32

Будет ли работать следующий класс (оставил только суть)?

```
class RCC_PLLCFGR {
private:
    enum {
        ADR = RCC_BASE + 0x04
    };
public:
    struct Bits {
        uint32_t PLLM   :6;
        uint32_t PLLN   :9;
        ...     
    };
    Bits & bits = *(Bits*)ADR;
};
```

При объявлении вызывается конструктор по умолчанию, который кинет объект точно по установленному адресу (адрес из мануала на контроллер)? И далее при работе с этим объектом я фактически смогу работать с регистром микроконтроллера, но как с битовым полем?

```
RCC_PLLFGR t;
t.bits.PLLN = 10;
```

Comment: Обычно доступ к регистрам осуществляют путем присваивания адреса регистра переменной типа указателя на структуру, которая описывает расположение регистров.

Comment: Знаю, как делают обычно, и мне это не подходит. В классе я могу создать кучу перечислений, с понятными смысловыми названиями значений всех битовых полей, а также понятные методы по работе с регистрами, а структуру bits сделать приватной и смотреть на заполнение битовых полей только при дебаге.

Comment: Ну так а что вам мешает это сделать внутри класса? Все с теми же понятными названиями, и спрятать в private.

Comment: Действительно, ничто не помешало. от ADR можно избавляться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно разместить объект класса точно по указанному адресу (нужный объем памяти при этом должен быть доступен), то к вашим услугам размещающий `new`:

```
class Type ....

...

Type * t = new(ptr) Type;
```

Comment: Не знаю считаются ли свободными управляющие регистры контроллера, но, помимо этого, мне в вашем случае не нравится, что адрес нужно указывать при инициализации, а я не хочу об этом думать, я не хочу даже знать реальный адрес регистра при создании объекта.

Comment: Тогда просто - конструктор в принципе никак не может влиять на то, где будет создан объект. Он вызывается, когда адрес уже известен. Это ответ на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Нужно уточнение.
При создании объект займет где-то свой минимальный байт (других полей, кроме ссылки на Bits же нет), но bits всё равно ссылается на нужный мне адрес (RCC_BASE + 0x04 в примере)? То есть цена вопроса 1 байт?

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, что за, гм... вы делаете? Вам нужно просто "наложить" структуру на адрес - так зачем при этом какие-то конструкторы?... `Type * t = (Type*)ptr;`

Comment: На это ответит только эксперимент. В понедельник на работе попробую, там дебагером можно всю карту памяти просмотреть. И предложение с new мне уже больше нравится. Можно создать кучу глобальных объектов на нужных адресах, которые по факту в памяти оперативной не занимают место.
А зачем это делаю, написал выше. Внутри класса помимо структуры еще методы по работе с ними будут, а структуру саму в приват кину.

Comment: Только не делайте никаких виртуальных функций - тогда vptr будет вмешиваться...

Comment: Внутри класса должна быть планарная структура с описанием регистров, по-другому это не работает. И вообще, использовать сильно абстрактные ЯП для работы с железом -- плохая затея. Вам ещё надо убедиться, что на один адрес не привязались два или более объектов.

Answer (score 2):

Самым лучшим решением было сделать, как тут и предлагали "наложить структуру на адрес" и не заворачиваться с конструкторами.
в результате код изменился.

```
class RCC_PLLCFGR {
public:
    struct Bits {
        uint32_t PLLM   :6;
        uint32_t PLLN   :9;
        ...     
    };
    Bits bits;
};

RCC_PLLFGR & t = (RCC_PLLFGR &) RCC->PLLFGR;
t.bits.PLLN = 10;
```